# Firefox webrtc audio issue

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I am not sure, is this a bug of firefox, why this demo web page i only could get video, but can't listen anything, even there is a audio icon at the tab.
https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html
My firefox version is 62, and system is MacOS 10.13.2.